# Android - Fragments and viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have one `FragmentActivity` which contains a `ViewPager`:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

Then in my `SectionsPagerAdapter` I have the following method which displays the layout for different positions:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position == 0){
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, FragmentA.class.getName());
    }
    else if(position == 1){
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, FragmentB.class.getName());
    }
    else if(position == 2){
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, FragmentC.class.getName());
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that the `FragmentC` calls `onCreateView` more than once, and this will recreate the view, I don't want that. I want it to be created once, and stay the same. `FragmentC` is at the position 2, then I swipe to position 1, it's ok. But when I swipe to position 0 and back to position 2 (`FragmentC)` it gets created again.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(nrOfPages);
```